# Can we merge the dynamics-crm and microsoft-dynamics tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[dynamics-crm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm) and [microsoft-dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics) are both for the same thing: Microsoft Dynamics CRM (all versions).

It fails the ["Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) test: "if any of them are synonyms then they should be merged."

Answer (score 2):

[*Moving question edit as answer - which is the fact*]

Microsoft Dynamics actually can refer to Microsoft Dynamics AX or Microsoft Dynamics GP or Microsoft Dynamics NAV. So, it appears to **not** be a synonym. CRM simply seems like the most popular type of Microsoft Dynamics question on here.

There could be an argument for burninating `microsoft-dynamics` though, since the other tags (`dynamics-crm`, `dynamics-gp`, etc.) are more helpful, and most people who work with one of the Microsoft Dynamics products do not also work with any of the other ones.

Comment: I agree. Most questions that use a [dynamics-XXX] tag (for sales, crm, 365, etc.) also use [microsoft-dynamics]. It is one of those global tags that are too large to be useful but then again, you will add them because it does not do any harm to your question.